# Empty set checking doesn't work on the first iteration

Tags: python, set

I have this loop I use to check for the occurrence of a list of words on a list of documents. What I want to get at the end is a list of all the documents where all of the words appear.

The datastructures are:

```
listOfTems = [term1, term2, ..., termN]
docs = {
    termJ = { docK: R }
    .
    .
    .
    termL = { docM: S }
}
# termJ appears in docK R times
```

This is the code:

```
firstTerm = True
for term in listOfTerms :
    if not firstTerm :
        docs = docs.intersection( docsWhere[term].keys() )
    else :
        docs = set( docsWhere[term].keys() )
        firstTerm = False
    if not docs :
        break
```

Since I want the intersection of the set, if at any point the set is empty there is no point to continue, so I get out of the loop. On the first iteration I need to make an exception and create the initial docs set with the docs that contain the first word, since I don't want to create an initial set with all the documents numbers, there are a LOT of documents.

The problem is, if the initial word does not appear on any documents (empty set), the loop still goes  for the second word, and then it exits the loop.

How can I make the loop stop on the first word?

Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary to have a `firstTerm` variable and check it every iteration of the for loop if you just handled the first term outside the `for` loop and did any remaining ones inside it (with `for term in listOfTerms[1:]:`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use enumerate to provide an index instead of tracking a first term boolean, then use the in-place `intersection_update` method, and I think this will solve your problems:

```
for index, term in enumerate(listOfTerms):
    if index == 0:
        docs = set(docsWhere[term].keys())
    else:
        docs.intersection_update(docsWhere[term].keys())
    if not docs:
        break
```

Or you could use `iter()` to create an iterable to simplify control flow, assuming you always get a non-empty list:

```
iter_listOfTerms = iter(listOfTerms)
docs = set(docsWhere[next(iter_listOfTerms)].keys())
for term in iter_listOfTerms:
    docs.intersection_update(docsWhere[term].keys())
    if not docs:
        break
```

If you don't always get a non-empty list, you need some more control flow

```
if listOfTerms:
    iter_listOfTerms = iter(listOfTerms)
    docs = set(docsWhere[next(iter_listOfTerms)].keys())
    for term in iter_listOfTerms:
        docs.intersection_update(docsWhere[term].keys())
        if not docs:
            break
else: # optional empty set if you didn't get a list with anything.
    docs = set()
```